# How are if conditions read?

Tags: c

In this exemple, if the first conditions is matched, are the other one tested by the compilator ?

```c
a = 10
if (a % 2 == 0 || a / 2 == 5 || a == 10)
   echo 'hello world'
```

Comment: This is known as short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: `echo 'hello world`? That's not a C statement. When creating a [mcve] make sure it's valid and replicates or clearly show the problem you ask about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In logical `or` conditions are checked from left to right.
If the left condition is `true` then remaining right conditions are not checked by the compiler.

`bool condition_1 = true;`
`bool condition_2 = false;`

`if(condition_1 || condition_2)` in this case `condition_2` is not checked by compiler.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but in the example of the OP is within an `if`